# memcpy erase variables in char array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I create multi dimensioanl array and write it to console

```
char a[5][10];

strcpy(a[0], "111111");
strcpy(a[1], "211112");
strcpy(a[2], "311113");
strcpy(a[3], "411114");
strcpy(a[4], "511115");


printf("size : %d \n", sizeof(a));

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d : %s \n",i,a[i]);
}
```

result is

```
size : 50 
0 : 111111 
1 : 211112 
2 : 311113 
3 : 411114 
4 : 511115
```

then I copy the array to another array, and write both of them to console

```
char a[5][10];
char b[][10]={"0"};

strcpy(a[0], "111111");
strcpy(a[1], "211112");
strcpy(a[2], "311113");
strcpy(a[3], "411114");
strcpy(a[4], "511115");

memcpy(&b,&a,sizeof(a));

printf("sizeof(a) : %d \n", sizeof(a));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d : %s \n",i,a[i]);
}

printf("sizeof(b) : %d \n", sizeof(b));
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d : %s \n",i,b[i]);
}
```

result is:

```
sizeof(a) : 50 
0 :  
1 :  
2 :  
3 :  
4 : 511115 
sizeof(b) : 10 
0 : 111111 
1 : 211112 
2 : 311113 
3 : 411114 
4 : 511115
```

what happened variables in a array ? why contents of a array are empty ?
I use `Ubuntu 14.04` and gcc version is `(Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`

Comment: Shouldn't even run. You're accessing uninitialised memory.

Comment: The moment you write 50 bytes from `a` into a 10 byte buffer of `b`, all bets are off.

Comment: Which length do you think the outer dimension of `b` has? What do you expect to happen? And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of `b` is too small to store all contents of `a`, so you accessed out of the allocated memory, which is very dangerous.

Do allocate enough memory.

```
char a[5][10];
char b[5][10]={{"0"}}; /* change this line */

strcpy(a[0], "111111");
strcpy(a[1], "211112");
strcpy(a[2], "311113");
strcpy(a[3], "411114");
strcpy(a[4], "511115");

memcpy(&b,&a,sizeof(a));

printf("sizeof(a) : %d \n", (int)sizeof(a)); /* change this line to pass data having correct type */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d : %s \n",i,a[i]);
}

printf("sizeof(b) : %d \n", (int)sizeof(b)); /* change this line to pass data having correct value */
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%d : %s \n",i,b[i]);
}
```

This code may show why the contents in `a` seems deleted: 0x00 is written to `a[i][0]` and `printf()` interpreted them as end of string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[5][10];
    char b[][10]={"0"};

    strcpy(a[0], "111111");
    strcpy(a[1], "211112");
    strcpy(a[2], "311113");
    strcpy(a[3], "411114");
    strcpy(a[4], "511115");

    memcpy(&b,&a,sizeof(a));

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) printf("%02X ", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to always state clear this invokes _undefined behaviour_. It is not just "very dangerous", but you are completely off-road.

Answer (score 0):

The memcpy overwrote the contents of the array a. Why did it do that?

The array b was allocated only 10 bytes, because `char b[][10]` means "allocate space for an array of 10-char strings, the number of strings being specified by the initializer." In your case, the initializer is "0", ie, one string. So it allocated space for one 10-char string.

Since the whole thing is on the stack, the layout is reversed. Thus, the location of b comes first, and then a.

So, when you write into b, it starts correctly, writes the first string. When you write the second string, it overflows into the array a's space and kills it. 4 times. The last string survives.

Comment: "Since the whole thing is on the stack, the layout is reversed." No, it need not be. In this case, `a` just happened to be after `b`.

Comment: The C language does not require uising a stack. At this level, there is no use in going into details which can vary with the next compiler version, some randomised heuristics, added code, etc. For a typical implementation, the stack layout can heavily vary, e.g. when re-using allocated space on the stack.

Comment: Yes, agree on both counts, technically. Just trying to be helpful to the asker, they're asking why the array `a` got trashed. In the given gcc version and the given OS, I think what I gave was a fair explanation.